# Kubernetes pod cannot attach to in-use volume

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-storage, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

I have a `deployment` (see minimal config below) with 2 replicas which write their logs to a `volume` provisioned via `PVC`. My problem is that if I try to upscale the number of replicas / update the deployment, then I receive an error that the pods cannot be attached to the volume:

```
0s          Warning   FailedAttachVolume       pod/POD_NAME
AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-XXXXXX" : rpc error: code =
Internal desc = [ControllerPublishVolume] Attach Volume failed with error
failed to attach XXXXXX volume to XXXXXXXX compute: Bad request with: [POST
https://SOME_URL], error message: {"badRequest": {"code": 400, "message":
"Invalid input received: Invalid volume: Volume XXXXXXXX status must be
available or downloading to reserve, but the current status is in-use.
(HTTP 400) (Request-ID: XXXXXXX)"}}
```

PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: csi-cinder-tiefighter
```

deployment (some metadata was omitted because it's useless):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    spec:
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
          whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app.kubernetes.io/name: my-label
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
          whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app.kubernetes.io/name: my-label
      shareProcessNamespace: true
      initContainers:
        - name: add-volume-log-permissions
          image: my-busybox-iamge
          command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
          args: [ "-c", "chown 1000:1000 MY_PATH" ]
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: MY_PATH
              name: volume-logs
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 100Mi
              cpu: 100m
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: MY_IMAGE
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: MY_PATH
            name: volume-logs
      volumes:
        - name: volume-logs
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myPvc
```

Now, how do I overcome this? I need the volume to store my logs and the deployment should have minimum 2 replicas.

Comment: Can you change your application to write its logs to stdout, and not a file?  Then the normal Kubernetes logging subsystem will be able to collect the logs, and your cluster administrators' favorite log aggregator will be able to display them.  You'd also be able to remove the vast majority of the YAML you show, and avoid this particular storage problem.

Comment: But then, how would I persist the logs? I have a requirement that these logs need to be persisted for the past 5 years for regulatory purposes

Comment: See [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the Kubernetes documentation.  Note that setting this up is a little more of a cluster-administration task than a programming task, and it might be better to ask for help on [sf], [devops.se], or another site more focused on system administration.

Comment: Generally you want a `StatefulSet` instead of a `Deployment` when you need the workload attached to persistent volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the access mode of your **PVC** from **Readwritemany** to **Readwriteonce**

After that you will try to increase, it might work

Answer (score 0):

Setup your deployment app with [kind: Statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and use [Volume Claim Templates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#volume-claim-templates) for your persistent volumes to be provisioned by PersistentVolume Provisioner for dynamic PVC [provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/).

I also noticed that you used [accessModes:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) `ReadWriteMany` wherein you want a PVC on your pods, `ReadWriteOnce` is more applicable unless you do have NFS for storage sharing.